# Does the range of PCA scores signify anything?

Tags: pca

Does the range of scores for each principal component tell you anything when performing principal component analysis? (Similar questions that don't quite address this point are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222/what-are-principal-component-scores) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/interpreting-pca-scores))

E.g., on these plots PC scores range from -10 to 10, to -100 to 100

[image: Random example]

Comment: Did you scale your data before performing PCA? Looks like no. If that’s the case, the numbers won’t mean much.

Comment: What would the scores mean if the data *had* been scaled?